# Implementation of Lokesh Dhakar's "Color Thief" library results in "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null"

Tags: javascript, color-thief

I am trying to implement Lokesh Dhakar's "Color Thief" library.

The expected outcome is to display dominant color and color palette immediately after upload.

My assumption is that there is going something wrong in the following part of the code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
          var img = document.getElementById('image_0');
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to file url
          extractColors(img.id);
      }
    });
  });
```

When I end up at `dcolor = colorThief.getColor(document.getElementById(image));`, the "Uncaught TypeError" occurs.

See my effort below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Based on "Color Thief" by Lokesh Dhakar</title>

  <meta name="description" content="Get the dominant color or color palette from an image.">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla%7CMontserrat:700">

<style>

element.style {
}

.image-section {
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

.image-wrap {
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1em;
    min-height: 240px;
    background-color: var(--hover-bg-color);
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-xl);
}

.run-functions-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 8rem;
    height: 8rem;
    margin-top: -4rem;
    margin-left: -4rem;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: var(--link-color);
    background-color: white;
    border: 4px solid var(--link-color);
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: var(--bold);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    outline: none;
}

.no-touch-label {
    display: inline;
}

.touch-label {
    display: none;
}

.target-image {
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-xl);
    transition: border-radius 0.2s 0.3s;
}

.target-image {
    display: block;
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: var(--border-radius-xl) var(--border-radius-xl) 0 0;
}

.dswatch {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
}

.swatchp {
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
}

.dswatch {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 32px;
    border-radius-large: 8px;
    border-radius-xl: 12px;
}

.swatchp {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    border-color: #000;
    border-radius: 32px;
    border-radius-large: 8px;
    border-radius-xl: 12px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-thief/2.3.0/color-thief.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/color-thief/2.3.0/color-thief.min.js"></script>

<script>

      var dcolor;
      var colorp;

      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
          if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
              var img = document.getElementById('image_0');
              img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to file url
              extractColors(img.id);
          }
        });
      });

      function extractColors(image){
        colorThief = new ColorThief();
        dcolor = colorThief.getColor(document.getElementById(image)); // error!
        document.getElementById('dswatch_0').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + dcolor[0] + ',' + dcolor[1] + ',' + dcolor[2] + ')';
        colorp = colorThief.getPalette(document.getElementById(image), 8);
        document.getElementById('swatchp_0').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + colorp[0][0] + ',' + colorp[0][1] + ',' + colorp[0][2] + ')';
        document.getElementById('swatchp_1').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + colorp[1][0] + ',' + colorp[1][1] + ',' + colorp[1][2] + ')';
        document.getElementById('swatchp_2').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + colorp[2][0] + ',' + colorp[2][1] + ',' + colorp[2][2] + ')';
        document.getElementById('swatchp_3').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + colorp[3][0] + ',' + colorp[3][1] + ',' + colorp[3][2] + ')';
        document.getElementById('swatchp_4').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + colorp[4][0] + ',' + colorp[4][1] + ',' + colorp[4][2] + ')';
        document.getElementById('swatchp_5').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + colorp[5][0] + ',' + colorp[5][1] + ',' + colorp[5][2] + ')';
        document.getElementById('swatchp_6').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + colorp[6][0] + ',' + colorp[6][1] + ',' + colorp[6][2] + ')';
        document.getElementById('swatchp_7').style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(' + colorp[7][0] + ',' + colorp[7][1] + ',' + colorp[7][2] + ')';
      }

</script>

<div class="image-section ">
      <div class="image-wrap"><input type='file' /><br><img class="target-image" id="image_0" alt="image_0" src="#"></div>
      <div class="swatches">
        <h6>Dominant color:</h6>
          <div class="dswatch" id="dswatch_0"></div>
        <h6>Color palette:</h6>
          <div class="swatchp" id="swatchp_0"></div>
          <div class="swatchp" id="swatchp_1"></div>
          <div class="swatchp" id="swatchp_2"></div>
          <div class="swatchp" id="swatchp_3"></div>
          <div class="swatchp" id="swatchp_4"></div>
          <div class="swatchp" id="swatchp_5"></div>
          <div class="swatchp" id="swatchp_6"></div>
          <div class="swatchp" id="swatchp_7"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at 'this' ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback/20279485#20279485

Comment: Please add a [mcve] that shows the actual problem in the question itself and don't just add some links to an external resource that may not be reachable for whatever reason.

Comment: You highlighted links as code. They're not code. Plus I'm sure you saw the big, red warning about linking to jsFiddle without a [mcve] in your question. Please do as you were asked and post a [mcve] here. LInks rot. Sites go belly up. Future visitors need a complete example here.

Comment: @JohnSheridan could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: Apologies, I'm under time pressure right now and cannot answer fully. I suggest that you put a breakpoint on the line    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]); // set src to file url.  Look at the this object and see if it is the object you expect it to be.

Comment: @JohnSheridan no worries! It results in "blob:null/3516a1eb-4462-40d1-94ee-4d8216ba27b3", so this might indeed be causing the problem, as "Color Thief" expects the actual image and not a blob object.

Comment: @JohnSheridan thanks for pointing me in the right direction, was able to resolve it!

Comment: Please add a new answer with the solution of your problem and don't edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution to my problem. See hereafter for the code snippet that should replace `window.addEventListener('load', function() { ... }`:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0]) {
          var img = document.getElementById('image_0');
          img.id = document.getElementById('image_0').id;
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0]);
          reader.onload = async function () {
            await getResult();
            function getResult(){
              img.src = reader.result;
            }
            extractColors(img.id);
          };
          reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
          };

      }
    });
```